# inner join query don't return any things

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I have a `php` code that use a `mySQL` query in it.
tables `users` and `conversation` and `main_profile` have true values to select after this query but query return nothing.

```
$sqlQuer = 
"SELECT `conversation`.from,`conversation`.text, `main_profile`.nik_name, `users`.id  
FROM `conversation` 
INNER JOIN `users` ON(`users`.username = `conversation`.to ) 
INNER JOIN `main_profile` ON(`users`.id = `main_profile`.user_id) 
WHERE `conversation`.to = '".$to."' 
AND `conversation`.read = '0'";

$result = mysql_query( $sqlQuer) or die (mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row[0] . "#TEXT#" . $row[1]. "#TEXT#" . $row[2] . "#CON#";
    $ids[] = $row['id'];
}
```

any Idea ?

Comment: why can't use `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: please refer this link ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join

Comment: No link is available here.

Comment: there seems nothing wrong with the query. can you provide the data sample you test with ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join

Comment: and why are you echoing `$row[0] , $row[1]`??? you should echo `$row['text'] , $row['from']`.... as per your query...

Comment: i have `user_id` = `id` = 70 and `username` = `to` = test

Comment: @NishantSolanki why it is wrong i have an array and can use index.

Comment: @MohammadRezaVahedi hmm sorry.. as `mysql_fetch_array` returns both `associative and numeric array`.. but have you tried left join or not??

Comment: I Change first join to LEFT JOIN  and second to RIGHT JOIN

Answer (score 1):

Query was solved with this change that First INNER JOIN changed to LEFT JOIN and second changed to RIGHT JOIN.